# thumbOffset doesn't work

Tags: android, android-layout

My app has a seekbar with custom thumbOffset. And it works incorrectly on some devices (e.g. my own Samsung Galaxy GIO Android 2.3.3)

(my app is built for Android 2.1 and I can't change it)

I've made a simple App with a seekbar and nothing else - thumbOffset still doesn't work on my phone (but works correctly on some other devices - see UPD):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:a="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          a:orientation="vertical"
          a:layout_width="fill_parent"
          a:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <SeekBar a:id="@+id/lights_downwash_slider"
         a:layout_width="280dp"
         a:layout_height="wrap_content"
         a:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
         a:layout_margin="5dp"
         a:thumbOffset="-15dp"
         a:maxHeight="20dp"
         a:minHeight="20dp"
         a:progress="0"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Did anyone have the same problem and has the solution?

UPD: 
works correctly on Samsung Nexus (android 4.0.4), on emulator 2.3 and 4.0.3

doesn't work on emulator 2.1 and Samsung Galaxy Gio (2.3.3)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got a same problem.
I solved this problem with equivalent API (setThumbOffset) at run-time. (not in design time with xml)

Refer to below equivalent API.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsSeekBar.html#setThumbOffset(int)